# In VB.NET, How to listen to the load event of any dropdown list in the application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have several dropdown lists in different pages of the app.

I need to **run some function when any dropdown is loaded** in the WHOLE APP.

I am trying the below but not working:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    GetAllDropdowns(Me.Page)
End Sub

Private Sub GetAllDropdowns(ByVal Ctrl As Control)
    Dim dd As DropDownList = Nothing
    For Each c In Ctrl.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is DropDownList Then
            dd = DirectCast(c, DropDownList)
            AddHandler dd.Load, AddressOf doIt
        Else
            GetAllDropdowns(c)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub doIt(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Do whatever....
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps provide some code? This can't be answered as the questions stands, as it is too broad.

Comment: plz check the updated post

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the event you are using.

The Page_Load event runs after all of the load events of the controls so the sub doIT won't run.

Try moving your code in the Page_Init event which seems more appropriate for this task.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more information about asp.net page life cycle.